# Can Ranunculus bulbs be re-used in cold climates?

Tags: flowers, bulbs, overwintering, storage

I've planted ranunculus for the first time this year in Minnesota (USDA zone 4). I beleive that these are not winter hardy here but can these be dug up, stored and replanted like dahlias, callas, gladiolus and the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Ranunculus do not have tuberous roots, so I'm assuming you've planted Ranunculus asiaticus, usually bought as small, clawed tubers. If that's the variety you have, yes, you can keep them over winter. In the UK, they're dug up in early October, the top foliage is removed if there's any left, and they're left to dry out a bit on a bed of sand in a tray or something, then they're planted in a sandy, dry mix and kept in a cool, darkish place, out of frost over winter, and started into growth in pots indoors the following early Spring (early March here). If your weather gets cold from September on, you may need to lift them in September instead.